# Connecting to database on server

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

Edited:
I'm trying to connect to my database but I'm stuck. 
I get the following error:

I have a mysql database and gain access to it using phpMyAdmin.

Here's my code (UPDATED):

```
    public class DBConnection 
{
static String user = "ademphotography_dk_financesjava";
public static  String pass = "******";
private static String db = "ademphotography_dk_financesjava";
protected static String url = "jdbc:mysql://ademphotography.dk.mysql";



public static Connection getConnection() 
{
    Connection conn;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url+"/"+db, user, pass);

        return conn;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've tried using the IP of the host:

```
 Protected static String url = "jdbc:mysql://XX.XX.X.XX:3306";
```

but that resulted in this error instead (but now I don't have problem with "unkown host"):

```
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: I believe you can see some Exception in the output? Can you also post the stack trace?

Comment: Don't you need a port (like 3306) in the URL? Have a look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: "I'm stuck" provides very little useful information about the behavior you are observing. Is a MySQL error being returned? Can the client resolve the hostname into an IP address? Is the process hanging? Can the mysql command line client or any other client connect from this same machine? (@ArthurNoseda: the port should be optional. It should default to 3306 if not provided, and would only need to provided if MySQL is running a port other than 3306.

Comment: @ArthurNoseda No you don't. The default port (3306) will be used.

Comment: This is the error message i get: 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: @Charles First of all, the correct url is `jdbc:mysql://host:port/database`, Please modify the question to include the **full output**, there should be several "Caused by" lines that can tell us more information. But from what I see, you probably are using wrong host and port.

Comment: @LukeLee, I've just modified it. There's just 1 error and that's it. It doesn't show where in the code there might be a problem, just that "Communications link failure". 

I've just checked again and it literally shows me what the host is and I've copy/pasted it - just like I did with the database reference. So I am using the correct host and database (ports not necessary, as it will use the default).

Comment: My bad, @LukeLee. There is one "Cause by" ..

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ademphotography.dk.mysql

However, I am 100 % sure that I typed in the correct host. PhpMyAdmin clearly states what the host is .

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this Java expression:

```
url+db
```

return this string:

```
jdbc://ademphotography.dk.mysqlademphotography_dk_financesjava
```

It seems like you need a literal slash character before the database name.

I'd expect that without the slash, that whole string "ademphotography.dk.mysqlademphotography_dk_financesjava" is going to be seen as a hostname.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I see that now. 
I've  just tried put the slash between them but now I get this error: 

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc://ademphotography.dk.mysql/ademphotography_dk_financesjava

Comment: Seems like you are missing the "mysql:" ...  `jdbc:mysql://hostname`

Comment: I've updated that, Spencer7593 :) ... Still no luck. I still get the "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure" error.

Comment: I think that you need to relist your entire block of code.  Also realize that communications link failure may be a temporary problem due to hardware or network problems.

Answer (score 0):

The connection must be in the form

```
jdbc:mysql://server/database
```

In your example the line please update the following two lines:

```
      protected static String url = "jdbc:mysql://ademphotography.dk.mysql";
```

`...`

```
      conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url+"/"+db, user, pass);
```

[edit: corrected a wrong line of code]

Comment: I've updated the two lines, thank you. However, it did not solve the problem. 
I get the following error now: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Is the server up and running and do you have access to it (firewall, username, etc)?
Can you access it from the command line?

Comment: Yes, it is up and running and I have complete access to it. 

I thought that maybe my jdbc wasn't included in my build path but I've triple checked and there isn't any problem there ... this is making me pull out my hair, lol.

Comment: Do you see any other error output when you run the code? There should be a stacktrace from the try/catch?

Comment: "Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ademphotography.dk.mysql"

That's the one ... clearly it shows there's something wrong with the host but I really don't understand why. In PhpMyAdmin it tells me the host is ademphotography.dk.mysql.

Comment: This indicates that the server name is wrong. I'm not too familiar with PhpMyAdmin, but could you check in there if you can find the IP address of the server and see if this works?
Do you have any other information about the server name?

Comment: I've just tried using the IP instead but that gives this error (instead of the unkown host error):


Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Did you use the IP of the PhpMyAdmin page or the server itself?
Can you check the configuration of  your PhpMyAdmin and see how it connects to the server? Does it use the standard port 3306?

Comment: These are the database information I have. 


Server: ademphotography.dk.mysql via TCP/IP
User: ademphotography_dk_financesjava@xx.xx.x.xx


 I used the IP of the server.
And yes, it uses the default port 3306 :)

Comment: Can you ping the MySQL server from the machine the Java code is running on - or connect via the MySQL command line tool? Is it the same as the PhpMyAdmin?
My guess is that you don't have access to the server from the Java machine.

Comment: I wrote (well, "borrowed") a code I found to ping to the server. It tells me that the host is NOT reachable :/

Comment: I think the problem is not you Java code (as above) - this should work if the parameters (server, db, user, pass) are ok.
It seems that your Java application cannot reach the MySQL server. This needs to be checked on the other end, i.e. the firewall or settings on the MySQL server.

Comment: Hmm maybe. I guess I'll have to try something else, then. 
I'll be back in some 12 hours or so. Going to sleep now (been trying to fix this for hours). Thanks for the help!